# SharePoint 2013: Creating Site Columns using CAML

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, site-column, caml

I had a SharePoint solution which is working perfectly in SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010.

The solution contained Site Columns that were created using CAML (XML Files).  Further I created a solution that just contained Site Columns element.xml.

The solution gets deployed perfectly in SharePoint 2010 and works.  But when I deploy it onto SharePoint 2013,  I don't see any site columns in the gallery.

Wanted to know if someone has already experienced this issue.  I will get the exact error message later onto this question (i dont have it right now).

- Sudhir

Comment: Provisioning site columns from caml XML works like a charm for me in 2013

Comment: Robert,  then it might have somethign to do with my elements.xml,  let me look onto detailed error and see if i find something..

Comment: Robert, I found something interesting in http://www.danlarson.com/upgrading-features-and-site-columns-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013/  "Custom columns need to be re-deployed to the 15 folder structure. Features that add custom columns will activate without error, but the custom columns will not be accessible, and the feature may fail to de-activate and re-activate. SharePoint requires columns to be deployed to the 15 structure in order to be used by code and to show up in the Site Columns dialog."

Comment: Interesting, so it is mainly the fact that you use an older solution and I a new one that makes it work or not work

Comment: Yups,  got to know today :)

Comment: Robert,  old WSP are targeted for v14.0 and that is how it deploys everything to 14/Hive,  updating the manifest to v 15.0 did the trick for me... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found solution to this,  setting the package version to 15.0 started putting the site columns file in 15\Hive folder.

Such an easy job :)